# Cshell and Awk Infinite Running

Tags: unix, putty, csh

When I run the below program, I get no return, however the program still runs forever until I end it.  Can some one please exoplain to me why this would happen.  I am trying to get this complex awk statement to work, however, have been very unsuccessful.

The code I am using for my Cshell is (its all on one line, but I split it here to make it easier to read):

```csh
awk '{split($2,b,""); counter = 1; while (counter < 13)
{if (b[counter] == 1 && "'$cmonth'" > counter)
{{printf("%s%s%s\n", $1, "'$letter'","'$year3'")}; counter++; 
else if (b[counter] == 1 && "'$cmonth'" <= counter) 
{{printf("%s%s%s\n", $1, "'$letter'","'$year2'")}; counter++;} 
else echo "fail"}}' fileRead >> $year$month
```

The text file I am reading from looks like

```
fff 101010101010
yyy 100100100100
```

Here `$year2` and `$year3` represent counters that start from 1987 and go up 1 year for each line read.
`$cmonth` is just a month counter from 1–12.
`$letter` is just a ID.

The goal is for the program to read each line and print out the ID, month, and year if the position in the byte code is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mismatched curly braces, I have reformatted to one standard of indentation.

```
awk '{ \
     split($2,b,""); counter = 1 \
     while (counter < 13) { \
         if (b[counter] == 1 && "'$cmonth'" > counter){ \
             printf("%s%s%s\n", $1, "'$letter'","'$year3'") \
             counter++ \
         } \
         else if (b[counter] == 1 && "'$cmonth'" <= counter) { \
             printf("%s%s%s\n", $1, "'$letter'","'$year2'") \
             counter++ \
         } \
         else print "fail" \
     }  # while \
}' fileRead >> $year$month
```

Also awk does'nt support `echo`.

Make sure that the `\` is the LAST char on the line (no space or tab chars!!!), or you'll get a syntax error.

Else, you can 'fold' up all of the lines into one line. adding the occasional ';' as needed.

**edit**

OR you can take the previous version of this awk script (without the `\` line continuation chars), put it in a file (without any of the elements outside of the `' ....'` (single quotes) and call it from awk as a file. You'll also need to made so you can pass the variables cmonth, letter, year2 and any others that I've missed.

1. save as file
2. edit file, remove any `\' chars, change all vars like "'$letter'" to letter **
3. call program like

**

```
 awk -v letter="$letter" -v year2="$year2" -v month="$month" -f myScript  fileRead >> $year$month
```

**

for example

```
 printf("%s%s%s\n", $1, "'$letter'","'$year2'")
```

becomes

```
printf("%s%s%s\n", $1, letter,year2)
```

IHTH.

Comment: Can you let me know where the occasional ";" would be?  I am very new to this stuff.

Comment: `;` separate statements in `c, awk, perl`, and many others. You don't want any trailing after a `}` char (usually). Your original code doesn't have any in the wrong place (except that `};` can be replaced with `}`.  Are you using the code as above, or trying to go back to 'all-on-one-line'? I can't see any good reason to do that. Good luck.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, again, reduce the scope of what you're doing, with the goal of understanding how the syntax works. Get the most basic cmd to work correctly, then keep adding in processing and syntax. Good luck.

Comment: Finally, responding to your headline, rather than infinitely running, it is more likely that your scripts are waiting for data to be sent to them, beucase you have a mispelled variable or other at the wrong spot in your code. I don't see that in what you've supplied, but it's clearly not your whole script.

Comment: I went back to all one line.  If I wanted to use your example above, how would I account for the line breaks?

Comment: I've modified my answer with my best guess as what you need. But I don't have access to a csh to test with. I've also added an alternate solution that is probably be better and help you move forward.